# Manage number of database connections in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, database-connection, amazon-rds

I deployed my WordPress application on `AWS EC2`  and the database is on Amazon RDS.
As per the property of RDS it `supports maximum 40 connections` but in my application, the hit rate is more than `15 users per seconds`, as a result, I am facing database connection error on my application.

I researched regarding to it and found that the WordPress application creates a new database connection on every application hit. Is it a property of WordPress or is there any efficient way in WordPress to manage the number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways which you need to explore in order to achieve this performance optimization.
1) you need to enable [W3TototalCache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) to enable DB side caching allowing many sites to reduce the time needed to generate new pages. This is especially useful for sites that receive a lot of comments

2) [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) which will allow you to generates static html files from your dynamic WordPress blog. After a html file is generated your webserver will serve that file instead of processing the comparatively heavier and more expensive WordPress PHP scripts.

Lastly ensure all your plugins updated along with the WordPress core.